# Using dictionary of GraphServiceClient is thread safe?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have to maintain number of graphClients in my application .
is it better way to store in dictionary? is it thread safe ?   what could be the best option ?

```
IDictionary<string, IGraphServiceClient> dict = new Dictionary<string, IGraphServiceClient>();  

    private IGraphServiceClient GetGraphServiceClient()
    {
        IDictionary<string, IGraphServiceClient> dict = new Dictionary<string, IGraphServiceClient>();
        var tenantIds = new List<string> { "Tenant1", "Tenant4", "Tenant1", "Tenant1" };
        foreach (var tenant in tenantIds)
        {
            var graphServiceClient = GetGraphServiceClient(tenant);
            var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync();
        } 
    }
```

```
    private IGraphServiceClient GetGraphServiceClient(string i)
            {
                if (!dict.ContainsKey(i))
                {
                    dict.Add(i, new GraphServiceClient(new MyAuthenticationProvider(i)));
                }
                return dict[i];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are not thread-safe. Moreover, even if a dictionary was thread-safe, the composite statements like

```
private IGraphServiceClient GetGraphServiceClient(string i)
{
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(i))
    {
        dict.Add(i, new GraphServiceClient(new MyAuthenticationProvider(i)));
    }
    return dict[i];
}
```

are never thread-safe. You need to guard this with a mutex.